# al insertar datos float en influxdb se guardan como integer

Tags: nodejs, angular

estoy realizando una aplicación web en **angular8, usando nodejs como servidor web e influxdb como base de datos**. Es primera vez que trabajo con este trío, pero no me es desconocido el trabajo con aplicaciones web.

Realizo la captura de los datos a través del formulario correctamente, y los envía al fichero de inserción en la bd correctamente. Mi problema es que cuando inserto en la bd, en vez de valor **float** me toma un **integer**, y al valor le quita todo detrás de la coma.
He puesto `console.log` para ver los valores luego de insertar y me lo muestra bien. Incluso, en la consola donde se corre nodejs veo que llegan los datos.

Intenté borrar la **tabla/measurement** en influxdb, e insertar los datos por primera vez por la web y los campos los toma integer. 
Borre la tabla e inserte el primer registro de forma manual(directamente en la BD) con

```
Insert Sensor,id=test lat=12.345,lat=-98.765
```

y pone los campos como float, pero cuando inserto desde la web me da

> ERROR:  { Error: partial write: field type conflict: input field "lat" on measurement "Sensor" is type integer, already exists as type float dropped=1

Este es mi codigo con el que inserto en la BD, como pueden ver me olvido de lo obtenido por el form y doy valores a las variables directamente, que son las mismas que envio

```
 router.post('/obtenerForm', function(req,res){
    console.log("Llegue al post in sever");
    console.log(req.body); 
    var id = req.body.id.trim();
    var lat = 12.345;
    var lon = -98.765;
    console.log("Valores de id " + id + " y lat "+lat + " y de lon " + lon);

     if (typeof req.body.id === 'string' && req.body.id.trim() != '') {
  //  var id = req.body.id.trim();
  var id = "hola";
    influx
      .query('Sensor')
      .where('id', id)
      .then(influxToJSON)
      .then(function (sensors) {
        if ( sensors.length > 0 ) {
          return res.status(400).jsonp({ message: "Ya existe un sensor con ID " + id });
        }

        influx
            .write('Sensor')
            .tag({
              id,
            })
            .field({
              lat: lat,
              lon: lon,
              val: 0,
              lastSeen: '',
              auth: true,
            })
            .then(() => {
              res.status(200).jsonp({ message: "Sensor registrado correctamente, Data received id "+ id + " lat " + lat + " lon "+lon})
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log('/obtenerForm ERROR: ', err);
              return res.status(500).jsonp({ message: "No se pudo guardar el sensor"+ id + " lat " + lat });
            });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('/obtenerForm ERROR: ', err);
        return res.status(500).jsonp({ message: "Error en la base de datos, Data received id "+ id + " lat " + lat });
      });
  } else {
    return res.status(400).jsonp({ message: "Se necesita el id del sensor" });
  }

//  res.status(200).send({"message":"Data received id "+ id + " lat " +lat});
  //res.status(200).send({"message":"Data received by the post server"});
})
```

Este es el código simplificado

Comment: Se necesita ver el código de lo que estás haciendo, porque sólo con la descripción que das es insuficiente. Puedes leer [mcve], para que tengas una idea. Saludos

Comment: gracias, es que andaba ya como loca y no me encontraba cerca de la PC, :)

Comment: Por lo que puedo leer en la [documentación](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-js/blob/master/examples/write.js), para usar el método [`writePoints()`](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-js/blob/master/packages/core/src/WriteApi.ts), debes crear los puntos usando la Interfaz o clase [`Point`](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-js/blob/master/packages/core/src/Point.ts). Tu simplemente estás pasando un objeto y puede ser que el problema se encuentre allí. Lamentablemente no conozco a fondo este módulo como para darte más ayuda. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras muchas gracias, actualicé mi pregunta con el método completo a lo mejor ve ahi algo que se me pasó por alto

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo tienes establecido tu esquema de datos? Creo que puedo darte una mano. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, no se ha que se refiere, es que con influxdb estoy totalmente perdida. Mi BD solo tiene 2 measurements, sensor y user, en mi pregunta puse los tags(id) y fields(lat,lon)